# make available only a subset of functions in python package

Tags: python, function, package

I am currently creating a package for python but I would like to give access to the user only a specific set of functions defined in this package. Let's say that the structure file is as follows:

```
my_package/
    __init__.py
    modules/
        __init__.py
        functions.py
```

In `functions.py`, there are several functions as below (those are silly examples):

```
def myfunction(x):
    return my_subfunction1(x) + my_subfunction2(x)

def my_subfunction1(x):
    return x

def my_subfunction2(x):
    return 2*x
```

I want the user to be able to import `my_package` and directly access `myfunction`, but NOT `my_subfunction1` and `my_subfunction2`. For example, let's say that only `myfunction` is useful for the user, whereas the sub-functions are only intermediate computations.

```
import my_package
a=my_package.myfunction(1) #should return 3
b=my_package.my_subfunction1(1) # should returns an error, function does not exist
```

I can think of two ways of solving my problem by adding the following lines to the `__init__.py` file inside `my_package/`

1/ `from modules.functions import myfunction`

2/ `from modules.functions import *`, and renaming the subfunctions with a leading underscore to exclude them from the starred import, ie :

`_my_subfunction1` and `_my_subfunction2`

and both of these tricks seems to work well so far.

My question is thus : Is this the correct "pythonic" way to do ? Which one is better ? If none of them is the good way, how should I re-write it ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23151400/how-do-i-write-module-private-protected-methods-in-python

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for, but the thread you mentionned is a good complement to the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should take a look at the [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) variable.

In your case, just set, in yout `__init__.py`:

```
__all__ = ['myfunction']
```